# Quotient vs Product Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

You are asked to differentiate
$$
y = \frac{x - 1}{x + 1}
$$
Looking at the question, I'm thinking I could solve this question using the product rule by making $\tfrac{1}{x + 1}$ into $(x + 1)^{-1}$.  Is there something I am not conceptually understanding about the two rules?

Comment: I cannot really judge upon your question (your understanding) from what you write, but of course you can use any of the two, if both lead to the desired result.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there's_more_than_one_way_to_skin_a_cat

Comment: You can definitely do that. Personally, I never use the quiotient rule, I always just convert such derivatives into the product rule. It sounds like you've got this down!

Comment: same here :-) quotient rule - Boooo!

Comment: While there is the temptation to avoid the quotient rule (as it's more complicated to remember), which is "better" depends on what you're doing with the derivative.  If you have to set the derivative equal to something and solve the resulting equation, then you're going to have to find a common denominator, in which case you have reconstructed the result of the quotient rule by hand.

Comment: yes ok - but the quotient rule gives the most obvious of all common denominators... quotient rule, booooo! x-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quotient rule and the product rule are the same thing.  In particular, the quotient rule follows from the product rule and the chain rule.  Recall that the product rule states that if $h(x) = f(x) g(x)$, then $$h'(x) = f'(x) g(x) + f(x) g'(x).$$  Also recall that the chain rule states that if $h(x) = f(g(x))$, then $$h'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x).$$  Therefore, if $$h(x) = f(x)/g(x) = f(x)\cdot \frac{1}{g(x)},$$ then the product rule gives $$h'(x) = f'(x) \cdot \frac{1}{g(x)} + f(x) \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{g(x)}\right].$$  Then the chain rule applied to the second term gives $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{g(x)}\right] = -(g(x))^{-2} g'(x).$$  Therefore, $$h'(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)} - \frac{f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2} = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use either of the two rules: the quotient rule or the product rule. If you try each approach, you'll see that they each lead to the same derivative, $y'$.

To simplify the function even further, You could also use the fact that $$y = \frac{x-1}{x+1} = y = \frac{x +1 - 1 - 1}{x+1} = 1 - \frac{2}{x+1} = 1 -2(x+1)^{-1}$$

Then $$y' = (-1)(-2)(x+ 1)^{-2} = \dfrac 2{(x+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can find the derivative using the *product rule,* provided that you also know the *chain rule.*  Since
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} \right] &= \frac{d}{dx} \left[ (x - 1) \cdot (x + 1)^{-1} \right] \\
&= \frac{d}{dx} (x - 1) \cdot (x + 1)^{-1} + (x - 1) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \left[ (x + 1)^{-1} \right].
\end{align}
$$
The last derivative is of the composite function
$$
x \mapsto (x + 1) \mapsto (x + 1)^{-1}.
$$

Comment: So you're saying chain rule is never used within quotient Rule?